# Simulation tools to validate the maths models of an unmanned surface vehicle (USV) with a manipulator

Tags: validation, model, simulation, robotics, manipulators

I'm working on a custom unmanned surface vehicle (USV) with a waterproof manipulator attached to it.

I'm looking for a simulator where I can validate the maths models of the robot.

The ideal case would be where

- I do not need to put equations to calculate the hydrodynamics in the simulator,
- but I can just put the geometry of my robot, force and torque inputs, and any other necessary parameters
- and see that both the USV and the attached manipulator are affected by corresponding hydrodynamics (buoyancy, drag, lift, and added mass)
- and the forces and torques (wrenches) propagated between the manipulator and the USV are also taken into account
- and the combined system (the USV and the manipulator) moves/behaves accordingly and accurately.

What would be the best simulation tool for this? Any other suggestions and advice would be appreciated as well.

Thank you very much.